# how to get datagridview current row column value?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform which has a gridview that is populating through a stored procedure the stored procedure is

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllCustumer]

    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  
    BEGIN TRAN
  BEGIN
SELECT     Customer.CustID, Customer.CustName, Customer.CompanyName, Customer.CompanyRealtion, Contract.ContractID, Contract.ContractDate, 
                  '$'+ CONVERT(varchar,Contract.totalPayment,1), '$'+ CONVERT(varchar,Contract.monthlyInstallment,1), '$'+ CONVERT(varchar,Contract.totalCommission,1), Contract.ContractDuration, Contract.PaymentMode, Contract.Description, 
                  Customer.Disable
FROM         Customer INNER JOIN
                  Contract ON Customer.CustID = Contract.CustID
WHERE     (Customer.Disable = 'false')

 END
commit
```

and I'm populating the gridview dynamically with this code

```
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MRDEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=Crystal_Accounts;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "spGetAllCustumer";
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.Clear();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I want to select the custID, contractID, totalpayment of the selectedRow i don't know how can i do it and second question is about the currency sign that i used in the storedprocedure is it right way or what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As volody pointed out, you can use the SelectedRows property to get everything you need. However, you might not know the indexes of the columns in question (although they're usually generated in the same order as the query, so make sure to alias the columns properly), you can use the column text itself via string access on the cells:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    // Do something with row.Cells["CustID"].Value;
    // Do something with row.Cells["ContractID"].Value;
    // Do something with row.Cells["TotalPayment"].Value;
}
```

The other thing I would suggest you do is to leave the formatting up to the DataGridView instead of the SQL query. This is generally best practice when separating your data access/business logic layer from your presentation/UI layer. The way you would do this would be to specify a `DataFormatString` on the DataTable's DataColumn for the columns in question. In this particular case, you would do this:

```
...
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
dt.Columns["TotalPayment"].DataFormatString = "C";
dt.Columns["MonthlyInstallment"].DataFormatString = "C";
dt.Columns["TotalCommission"].DataFormatString = "C";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

The downside to doing everything in code is that you don't get any design-time support, meaning you have to test everything out during run-time (which could be time consuming). That's one of the reasons ORM's are used (such as the VS DataSet Designer, LINQ2SQL designer, EntityFramework, etc), so that you have design-time support of database queries/objects. It makes it even easier to bind these data classes directly to UI controls at design-time and determine everything about the presentation layer before even running the code (such as which columns will be hidden, any additional computed columns, special column formatting, conditional row/column/cell painting, etc).

Just my $0.02 worth.

Comment: What is **dr** in **dt.Load(dr)**

Comment: I just took your code and added those three lines to it. Just be sure to properly alias your columns, otherwise finding them is going to be nothing but guesswork at the UI layer.

Comment: `DataFormatString`. Use Intellisense to get the exact property that you need to set.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) collection

```
int columnOfcustID = 0; // change this to correct custID column index
int columnOfcontractID = 1; // change this to correct contractID column index
int columnOftotalpayment = 2; // change this to correct totalpayment column index
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[columnOfcustID].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[columnOfcontractID].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[columnOftotalpayment].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you would override the select event.

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{

   GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

   //get value from cells
   String var = row.Cells[1].Text; 

   //do something with the value or pass the values to a function here
   DoSomething(var);
}
```

You could also create the columns in your code...

Using a TemplateField you could evaluate your dollar amounts to a label or another control using the following syntax

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Payment">
<itemTemplate>
    <asp:label id="lblTotalPayment" Text='<%# Eval("TotalPayment","{0:C}") %>' runat="server" />
</itemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However to go that route you would have to setup all the fields and not just one.

Comment: This is for WinForms DataGridView, not the Web.UI GridView. However, the logic is pretty similar to what you're suggesting anyway.